# Using struts2 json plugin

Tags: java, json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I have an abstract class that looks like the following with appropriate getters and setters for private properties (left out to keep the post sort):

```
public abstract class CityDistanceAwareAction extends BaseAction implements Preparable {
  private CityDistanceRepository cityDistanceRepository;

  private CityRepository cityRepository;

  private String cityA;

  private String cityB;

  private CityDistance cityDistance;

  public void prepare() {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cityA) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(cityB)) {
      CityPair cityPair = new CityPair(getCityRepository().findByName(cityA), getCityRepository().findByName(cityB));
      setCityDistance(getCityDistanceRepository().load(cityPair));
    }
  }
}
```

And then I have a very simple Class that looks like the following:

```
public class SearchCityDistanceAjaxAction extends CityDistanceAwareAction {

  @Override
  public String perform() {
    if (getCityDistance() == null) {
      addActionError("No city distance found for that pair");
      return ERROR;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
  }
}
```

The idea is that I can send in a String cityA and String cityB.  Do my look-ups and simply return the `cityDistance` object via AJAX.

When I set my `struts.xml` action up as follows:

```
<action name="searchCityDistance" class="searchCityDistanceAjaxAction">
  <result type="json">
    <param name="includeProperties">
      cityDistance.*
    </param>
  </result>
  <result name="error" type="json">
    <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
    <param name="includeProperties">
      actionErrors.*
    </param>
  </result>
</action>
```

I get the following return:

> (CommonsLogger.java:68) - Adding include property expression: 
>   cityDistance.* (CommonsLogger.java:68) - [JSON]{}

But I expected to get the `cityDistance.*` object back provided by the getter in the abstract `CityDistanceAwareAction`.

Interestingly enough if I add a special getter on the `SearchCityDistanceAjaxAction` object like the following:

```
  public CityDistance getAjaxCityDistance() {
    return getCityDistance();
  }
```

and change the struts file to:

```
  <result type="json">
    <param name="includeProperties">
      ajaxCityDistance.*
    </param>
  </result>
```

It gives me what I expected from my first attempt.

> (CommonsLogger.java:68) - Adding include property expression: 
>   ajaxCityDistance.* (CommonsLogger.java:68) -
>   [JSON]{"ajaxCityDistance":{"cityPair":{"cityA":{"cityName":"American
>   Falls","id":68},"cityB":{"cityName":"Ririe","id":119}},"distance":85}}

It would be ideal to remove the getter from my `SearchCityDistanceAjaxAction` as a getter is already provided in the parent.  Is there something I am missing here or is this the way it should function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a public `getCityDistance()` method in your `CityDistanceAwareAction` class?

Comment: Yes, there is a `getCityDistance()` method in the `CityDistanceAwareAction`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to change my struts.xml file to the following:

```
<action name="searchCityDistance" class="searchCityDistanceActionAjaxAction">
  <result type="json">
    <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
    <param name="excludeProperties">
      cityDistanceRepository
    </param>
    <param name="includeProperties">
      cityDistance.*
    </param>
  </result>
  <result name="error" type="json">
    <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
    <param name="includeProperties">
      actionErrors.*
    </param>
  </result>
</action>
```

But it still smells a little fishy to use the excludeProperties to leave out my cityDistanceRepository.  If this is how has to be I guess that is what I will do but hopefully there is a better solution.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/json-plugin.html - It clearly states that includeProperties takes regex expression and hence cityDistance.* matches all fields with cityDistance in its name. You can simply skip the (.*) thing and it'll work as expected without exludeProperties.

Comment: @coding_idiot  You see thats what I though but... When I do only cityDistance it sends an empty object.

Comment: @coding_idiot okay so I went in this morning when I got into work and tried what you suggested.  I removed the `.*` and the `excludeProperties` and i get the following returned `(CommonsLogger.java:68) - Adding include property expression:  cityDistance` and `(CommonsLogger.java:68) - [JSON]{"cityDistance":{}}`   as you can see it is empty :-(

Comment: Is "CityDistance " serializable ?

Comment: @coding_idiot yes indeed it is.  Had to double check but it is serializable.   As are its components.